# CronJob Runs but Does Not generate output

Tags: java, cron

I have a shell script which executes a java class and it is supposed to run weekly using Cronjob.
Last few days it hasn't been working as expected.
It does not generate any kind of logs or output.
checked `/var/logs` ,the `cronjob` looks like it is running on the time it has been scheduled to.
Also , if i manually run/execute the java class it works perfectly fine.
Any idea why cron isn't working?

**PS:** A similar shell script scheduled at a different time running the same java class is working without a problem.

Comment: Can you please include the cron initiation here (cron.d/cronttab) here in your question.  Rename anything that may be sensitive.

Comment: Is the cron'ed command or the Java program generating the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is if we have any ideas why cron isn't working. Based on what you wrote, I think that you probably recently moved the input or output file. It may run when you execute it manually but cron runs from a different location, so you have to use full paths to all files and commands, please try this. Source: Experienced same problem

Best Regards

Comment: @FernadoG your link **Source: Experienced same problem** is not working/non existent

Comment: Sorry, I am new and didn't mean to put a link, I'll edit.@ inkalimeva

Comment: exactly.. the input file for the cron was being received after the cron had finished running. Just had to reschedule the cron . Thanks for your suggestions